# RabbitMQ Ignore Header Content-Type

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When reading a Queue / Exchange rabbitMQ using `spring-boot-stream`, it is returning the following  `Exception`:

```
Unable to deserialize [br.com.foo.Bar] using the contentType [application/x-java-object;type=br.com.foo.Bar] br.com.foo.Bar; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I understand that the class `bar` is not found in this `package` in my application, but I would like to receive this message by ignoring the contentType, so I can receive the message in any class that implements the attributes.

Is there a way to skip or bypass this [header](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR4/multi/multi_contenttypemanagement.html) ?

```
@EnableBinding(CustomExchange.class)
public class RabbitService {

    @StreamListener(target = CustomExchange.INPUT)
    public void recievedMessage(Message<br.etc.Bar> msg) {
        try {
            Bar bar = msg.getPayload();

            //faz algo
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // faz algo
        } 
    }
}
```

## Import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you upgrade to 2.0.1? It uses JSON instead of Kryo for the default serialization technology.

With 1.3.x you can change to JSON by setting the outbound binding's contentType to `application/json`.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So52938080Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52938080Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void listen(Message<Bar> message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            output.send(new GenericMessage<>(new Foo("baz")));
        };
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public Foo() {
            super();
        }

        public Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

    }

    public static class Bar {

        private String bar;

        public Bar() {
            super();
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bar [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=foo
```

and

> GenericMessage [payload=Bar [bar=baz], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=foo, amqp_receivedExchange=foo, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=foo.foo, amqp_redelivered=false, id=7b45c26e-52d6-4889-b7bc-16c9ade11941, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-GGu9q7nO6KTpZ-NRwTe9xA, contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, timestamp=1540247495149}]

Comment: Can I use version 2.0.1 with spring boot 1.5.4? Importantly in the application, you are accusing the following exception: NoClassDefFoundError: org / springframework / integration / support / converter / ConfigurableCompositeMessageConverter.

Comment: No; 2.0 needs Boot 2.0.x. The current Boot 1.5.x is 1.5.17. It works fine for me; perhaps you still have old messages in the queue? I have edited my answer to show a working sample.

Comment: No, it's a local queue of tests, where I simulate the content-type of the server queue. On contentype, I'm not allowed to change from x-java-object to application / json.

Comment: Then I am afraid you are out of luck; Kryo serialization is like java serialization; you need the class to deserialize. You need to switch to a more general serialization strategy such as JSON or Avro.

Comment: Okay, I'll try other strategies. Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: There might be a way to write a custom Kryo deserializer; but I don't have any experience with that.